# transposed with one select sql

Tags: sql, transpose

Can the first table be transposed with one select sql to get the second table as shown?
I have tried this below but it is far from perfect.

```
'SELECT table1.licence_no, table1.plateno, table1.desc,      
MAX(CASE WHEN axle_no = 1 THEN axle_dist ELSE NULL END) AS axle_dist_1,
MAX(CASE WHEN axle_no = 2 THEN axle_dist ELSE NULL END) AS axle_dist_2,
MAX(CASE WHEN axle_no = 3 THEN axle_dist ELSE NULL END) AS axle_dist_3,
MAX(CASE WHEN axle_no = 4 THEN axle_dist ELSE NULL END) AS axle_dist_4,
MAX(CASE WHEN axle_no = 5 THEN axle_dist ELSE NULL END) AS axle_dist_5,
from table1
group table1.licence_no, table1.plateno, table1.desc;'
```

[image]

Comment: What does *far from perfect* actually mean? The query looks basically correct for what you need.

Comment: My query results A1 and B1 is in 2 rows. I'd like them in 1 row.

Comment: Hi @sievy, show us how do you want them in one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()` in a subquery to enumerate the `plateno` (or `plateno`/`desc` combination) and then use conditional aggregation for those columns:

```
SELECT t1.licence_no,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN t1.plateno END) as plateno_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN t1.desc END) as desc_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN t1.plateno END) as plateno_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN t1.desc END) as desc_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN axle_no = 1 THEN axle_dist ELSE NULL END) AS axle_dist_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN axle_no = 2 THEN axle_dist ELSE NULL END) AS axle_dist_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN axle_no = 3 THEN axle_dist ELSE NULL END) AS axle_dist_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN axle_no = 4 THEN axle_dist ELSE NULL END) AS axle_dist_4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN axle_no = 5 THEN axle_dist ELSE NULL END) AS axle_dist_5
from (select1 t1.*,
              dense_rank() over (partition by license_no order by plateno) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
group t1.licence_no;
```

Comment: I got a squiggly line under "over" saying syntax error: 'missing closing parenthesis'.
My MySQL does not recognise "dense_rank()".  I might not have some privilege to use it?

Comment: @sievy . . . This is Standard SQL and your database is not tagged with any database.